# How to insert a wide table into a page that is formatted with two columns

Tags: microsoft-word, layout

I have a Word document in which all text is written in 2 columns. I want to insert a table that is wider than a column, so ideally it should be inserted across both columns. But when I paste in the table, it becomes small to fit in just one column. How can I widen the table to fit two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around solution (if you don't mind doing a little bit of manual hacking) is to just create a textbox, place it where ever you like, and then add the Table into that. This way, you are not constrained by the boundaries of each column.

This has some draw backs, such as you may need to manually keep moving the textbox's position on screen as the content changes but depending on your situation, this may or may not suffice.